# What are the major, reliable taxi apps in Israel nowadays?

Tags: israel

What are the alternatives to Uber in Israel (other than public transit)?  I am more interested in reliable than cheapest.

Answer (score 7):

[Gett](https://www.gett.com/il/) and [Yango](https://yango.com/en_int/). Uber works too.

Or you can call the dispatchers directly as in good old days.

Israeli taxis, through the app or not, have to charge per the "counter" - the taximeter installed in the car.

Comment: Are you saying that the price displayed in the app is not the price you pay, rather you pay the price on the meter?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC they try to estimate, but in the end it has to be the meter. You can ask the driver to show you the meter (it must be visible anyway)

Comment: If you do not use the meter, can you just pay the price displayed by the app?

Comment: Yes, as long as both you and the driver agree ahead of time.